# How to handle concurrent modifications in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a project(like e-commerce) using Django and integrate it with android. (I am not building website, I am trying mobile only, so I am using *django-rest-framework* to create api)

So my question is how to handle a case where two or more users can book an item at the same time when there is only a single item. (basically how to handle concurrent modification and access of data) ?

Please help. I am stuck on this one.

Comment: You will need to write a custom ApiView in DRF and use [Django transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/) to ensure atomicity.

Comment: hey thanks on that, but do you have any example sort of so that i can understand better.? Also i found this link (https://github.com/debrouwere/django-locking). Can  use this ?

Answer (score 0):

`django-locking` is the way to go.